# Export only the plot into png in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to export only the plot excluding all the axes and the padding on each side of the  plot in Matlab. 
I removed the axes using the command :

```
  set(gca, 'Visible','off');
```

Any idea how exclude the padding as well from the plot ?

Thanks

I am looking for an image after exporting the plot someething like this :
[image]

What I am currently getting is :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This should be enough (you may also need to change the figure background color):

```
axis off
set(gca,'Position',get(gca,'OuterPosition'));
```

Basically, the axis settings contain several different position values; `Position` is the bounding box around the actual graph, `TightInset` the  bounding box which also incorporates the axis labels etc., `OuterPosition` the outermost.  Setting the innermost `Position` to equal `OuterPosition` just expands your graph to fill the plotting space.